# HighCharts not plotting decimal values in x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to plot decimal values on my x-axis, but each of my data points gets placed only on my major tick marks (at whole numbers). I'm using an array of [x,y] paired data, e.g. [[35,1500], [35.21,2000], [35.72,3500], [36.32,4000]]

What is happening, is the first item get's placed over the starting value (35), the second value (x 35.21) is being placed directly over 36, the next value (x 35.72) gets placed over 37, etc. It's as if the x-value in my data is being ignored.

Here is the chart's setup attributes:

```
chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        spacingRight: 10,
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
          text: null
    },

    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: true,
        tickInterval: 1,
        minorTickInterval: 10,

        labels: {
            step: 1
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'total$'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {                
            pointStart: 35,                                
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            shadow: false,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            },
            threshold: null
        }
    },
    series: [
         {
            //index: 1,
            name: 'trajectory$',                                                                       
            data: progressUpdateData,               
         }
     ]
```

How do I get the x-values plotted properly?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle showing your points in-between whole numbers
http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/2462/

```
plotOptions: {
    area: {                
        pointStart: 35,      
        pointPlacement: 'between',                          
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        shadow: false,
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },
        threshold: null
    }
}
```

You might want to look at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.pointPlacement as maybe you have this set to `"on"` instead of `"between"` somewhere?

Comment: awesome, thanks for the help! And thanks for posting the fiddle, that helped me solve something else, as well.

Comment: Great! If this answered the question, you should click the check to "accept the answer". See more [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

Will's answer didn't work for me. However, setting a [min](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min) and a [max](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max) to `yAxis` did. If you have these values `[[35,1500], [35.21,2000], [35.72,3500], [36.32,4000]]`, you simply set a minimum of `35` and a maximum of `37`.

**This**

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'total$'
    }
},
```

**became this**

```
yAxis: {
    min: 35,
    max: 37,
    title: {
        text: 'total$'
    }
},
```